# The icon that hides and seek right sidebar in shinydashboardPlus() is not working

Tags: r, shinyjs, shinydashboardplus

In the `shinydashboardPlus()` below I activate and deactivate the right sidebar ability based on the tab I use. The issue is that when Im in the 2nd tab I cannot hide the right sidebar by clicking on the icon above it.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar()
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (input$tabA == "Front") {
      hide(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      removeClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
    } else {
      show(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
      addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now we can use `shinydashboardPlus::updateControlbar`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$script(HTML("$(document).find('body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul').css('display', 'none');")),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar(id = "dashboardControlbarID", collapsed = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$tabA, {
    if (input$tabA == "Front") {
      hide(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
    } else {
      show(selector = "body > div.wrapper > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul")
    }
    updateControlbar("dashboardControlbarID")
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: tnx maybe you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73827723/apply-plotly-click-to-more-than-2-plots-in-a-shiny-app