# Apply plotly_click to more than 2 plots in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In the `shiny` app below I click on a point of my 1st line chart and subset the 2nd linechart. If I choose to click first on the 2nd linechart then I subset the 1st linechart.

But what if I had a third line chart and wanted to apply the same logic. Basically when I click on any chart first then the other 2 should be subsetted according to it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
linedat1<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                  18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                  18620, 18621), class = "Date"), n_cases = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                              1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
                                                                              ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

linedat2<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                            18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                            18620, 18621), class = "Date"), n_events = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
                                                                                        ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

linedat3<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                            18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                            18620, 18621), class = "Date"), n_objects = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
                                                                                         ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ui <- tags$body(

  dashboardPage(
    
    # ----header----
    header = dashboardHeader(

    ), 
    
    # ----sidebar----
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      

    ), 
    
    # ----body----
    body = dashboardBody(
     
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      plotlyOutput("plot3"),

      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
    if(is.null(myPlotEventData2())){
      p<-ggplot(data = linedat1, aes(x=date, y = n_cases)) +
        geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
        geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=0.5) +
        geom_point(size=1, color="#69b3a2")+ scale_color_grey() + theme_classic()+
        labs(title="Cases per month",x="Date", y = "Cases")
      ggplotly(p,source = "myPlotSource", customdata = ~date)
    }
    else{
      linedat1<-subset(linedat1,date %in% myPlotEventData2()[1,3])
      p<-ggplot(data = linedat1, aes(x=date, y = n_cases)) +
        geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
        geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=0.5) +
        geom_point(size=1, color="#69b3a2")+ scale_color_grey() + theme_classic()+
        labs(title="Cases per month",x="Date", y = "Cases")
      ggplotly(p)
    }
    
  })
  
  myPlotEventData <- reactive({
    event_data(
      event = "plotly_click",
      source = "myPlotSource")
  })
  myPlotEventData2 <- reactive({
    event_data(
      event = "plotly_click",
      source = "myPlotSource2")
  })
  output$plot2<-renderPlotly({
    if(is.null(myPlotEventData())){
      p<-ggplot(data = linedat2, aes(x=date, y = n_events)) +
        geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
        geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=0.5) +
        geom_point(size=1, color="#69b3a2")+ scale_color_grey() + theme_classic()+
        labs(title="Cases per month",x="Date", y = "events")
      ggplotly(p,source = "myPlotSource2", customdata = ~date)
    }
    else{
      linedat2<-subset(linedat2,date %in% myPlotEventData()[1,3])
      p<-ggplot(data = linedat2, aes(x=date, y = n_events)) +
        geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
        geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=0.5) +
        geom_point(size=1, color="#69b3a2")+ scale_color_grey() + theme_classic()+
        labs(title="Cases per month",x="Date", y = "events")
      ggplotly(p)
    }
    
  })
  output$plot3<-renderPlotly({
      p<-ggplot(data = linedat3, aes(x=date, y = n_objects)) +
        geom_area( fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.4) +
        geom_line(color="#69b3a2", size=0.5) +
        geom_point(size=1, color="#69b3a2")+ scale_color_grey() + theme_classic()+
        labs(title="Cases per month",x="Date", y = "objects")
      ggplotly(p)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create separate filtered datasets for each plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

linedat1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                              18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                              18620, 18621), class = "Date"), 
                           n_cases = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)),
                      row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

linedat2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                              18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                              18620, 18621), class = "Date"), 
                           n_events = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)),
                      row.names = c(NA, -15L),
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

linedat3 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18599, 18600, 18604, 18606, 
                                              18607, 18608, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18614, 18615, 18618, 18619, 
                                              18620, 18621), class = "Date"), 
                           n_objects = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L)),
                      row.names = c(NA, -15L),
                      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ui <- tags$body(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(), 
    body = dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      plotlyOutput("plot3")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())) {
      displaydat1 <- subset(linedat1, date %in% myPlotEventData2()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat1 <- subset(linedat1, date %in% myPlotEventData3()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat1 <- linedat1
    }
    p <- ggplot(data = displaydat1, aes(x = date, y = n_cases)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "Date", y = "Cases")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource1", customdata = ~ date)
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat2 <- subset(linedat2, date %in% myPlotEventData1()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat2 <- subset(linedat2, date %in% myPlotEventData3()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat2 <- linedat2
    }
    p <- ggplot(data = displaydat2, aes(x = date, y = n_events)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "Date", y = "events")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource2", customdata = ~ date)
    
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat3 <- subset(linedat3, date %in% myPlotEventData1()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())){
      displaydat3 <- subset(linedat3, date %in% myPlotEventData2()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat3 <- linedat3
    }
    p <- ggplot(data = displaydat3, aes(x = date, y = n_objects)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "Date", y = "objects")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource3", customdata = ~ date)
  })
  
  myPlotEventData1 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource1")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData2 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource2")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData3 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource3")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: in plotly you can also use the `source` argument across multiple plots - but in this scenario we need to distinguish where the click event originated.

PPS: as a faster alternative to re-rendering the plot you could use `plotlyProxy` to replace the underlying data. [Here](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/6) you can find an example.

Comment: I altered the dataset a little bit based on your mrthod an encountered an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860717/converting-date-column-with-as-date-cause-problem-to-the-subset-of-my-dataset