# Converting date column with as.Date() cause problem to the subset of my dataset

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In the shiny app below I use `plotly_click_event` to subset my plots on the plot I make a selection. For some reason the date column seems to cause me problems when I click on a dot and I get  `Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(bupaR)
pr59<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", 
                                 "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4120666", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", 
                                 "WC4120667", "WC4121068"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110, 110, 
                                                                          120, 110, 130, 120, 10, 130), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4120666-CN354878", "WC4120667-CSW308", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4121068-CSW303", "WC4120667-CSW309", "WC4121068-CSW308"), 
                     activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", 
                                  "SOLO Oil", "Tempering", "TCE Cleaning"), resource = c("3419", 
                                                                                         "3216", "3409", "3201", "C3-100", "3216", "C3-080", "C3-030", 
                                                                                         "C3-090", "C3-080"), timestamp = structure(c(1606964400, 
                                                                                                                                      1607115480, 1607435760, 1607568120, 1607630220, 1607670780, 
                                                                                                                                      1607685420, 1607710800, 1607729520, 1607744100), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             "POSIXt")), .order = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("eventlog", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              cols = list(case_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), lifecycle = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), action = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), activity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), resource = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), delim = ";"), class = "col_spec"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "lifecycle", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
ui <- tags$body(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(), 
    body = dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      plotlyOutput("plot3")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())) {
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData2()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData3()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat1 <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat1|> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = n_cases)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "Cases")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource1", customdata = ~ date)
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData1()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData3()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat1 <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat1|> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = n_cases)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "events")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource2", customdata = ~ date)
    
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData1()[1, 3])
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())){
      displaydat1 <- subset(pr59, timestamp %in% myPlotEventData2()[1, 3])
    } else {
      displaydat1 <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat1|> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x =date, y = n_cases)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "objects")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource3", customdata = ~ date)
  })
  
  myPlotEventData1 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource1")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData2 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource2")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData3 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource3")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your above code was, that you were trying to compare a full timestamp with a date object. Furthermore the `customdata` or `key` parameter belongs in the `aes` call of the `ggplot` (your approach would work with `plot_ly()`).

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(bupaR)

pr59<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", 
                                 "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4120666", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", 
                                 "WC4120667", "WC4121068"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110, 110, 
                                                                          120, 110, 130, 120, 10, 130), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4120666-CN354878", "WC4120667-CSW308", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4121068-CSW303", "WC4120667-CSW309", "WC4121068-CSW308"), 
                     activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", 
                                  "SOLO Oil", "Tempering", "TCE Cleaning"), resource = c("3419", 
                                                                                         "3216", "3409", "3201", "C3-100", "3216", "C3-080", "C3-030", 
                                                                                         "C3-090", "C3-080"), timestamp = structure(c(1606964400, 
                                                                                                                                      1607115480, 1607435760, 1607568120, 1607630220, 1607670780, 
                                                                                                                                      1607685420, 1607710800, 1607729520, 1607744100), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             "POSIXt")), .order = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("eventlog", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              cols = list(case_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), lifecycle = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), action = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), activity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), resource = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), delim = ";"), class = "col_spec"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "lifecycle", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
ui <- tags$body(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(), 
    body = dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      plotlyOutput("plot3")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())) {
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData2()$customdata))
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData3()$customdata))
    } else {
      displaydat <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat |> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = n_cases, customdata = date)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "Cases")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource1")
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData1()$customdata))
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData3())){
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData3()$customdata))
    } else {
      displaydat <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat|> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = n_cases, customdata = date)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "events")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource2")
    
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData1()$customdata))
    } else if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())){
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData2()$customdata))
    } else {
      displaydat <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat |> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x =date, y = n_cases, customdata = date)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "objects")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource3")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData1 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource1")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData2 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource2")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData3 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource3")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks can I reset them back based on your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894392/reset-subseted-dataframe-to-its-initial-form-by-using-actionbutton

Comment: and here a similar one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895140/use-plotly-click-event-to-subset-other-plot-in-shiny-app