# Use plotly click event to subset other plot in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In the `shiny` app below Im trying to subset those 2 charts which use the same dataset `pr59` by using `plotly_click_event`. While Im able to subset the second by clicking on the 1st I cannot do the opposite.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)

pr59<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689", 
                                 "WC4121068", "WC4120667", "WC4120666", "WC4120667", "WC4121068", 
                                 "WC4120667", "WC4121068"), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110, 110, 
                                                                          120, 110, 130, 120, 10, 130), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752", "WC4121068-CN301950", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4120667-CSW310", "WC4120666-CN354878", "WC4120667-CSW308", 
                                                                                                                   "WC4121068-CSW303", "WC4120667-CSW309", "WC4121068-CSW308"), 
                     activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
                                  "BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", 
                                  "SOLO Oil", "Tempering", "TCE Cleaning"), resource = c("3419", 
                                                                                         "3216", "3409", "3201", "C3-100", "3216", "C3-080", "C3-030", 
                                                                                         "C3-090", "C3-080"), timestamp = structure(c(1606964400, 
                                                                                                                                      1607115480, 1607435760, 1607568120, 1607630220, 1607670780, 
                                                                                                                                      1607685420, 1607710800, 1607729520, 1607744100), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             "POSIXt")), .order = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("eventlog", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              cols = list(case_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), lifecycle = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), action = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), activity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), resource = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), delim = ";"), class = "col_spec"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "lifecycle", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
ui <- tags$body(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      actionButton("res","RESET")
    ), 
    body = dashboardBody(
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
    
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData2())){
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, activity %in% myPlotEventData2()$customdata)
    } 
    else {
      displaydat <- pr59
    }
    dat <- displaydat |> group_by(date = as.Date(timestamp)) |> bupaR::n_cases()
    p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = n_cases, customdata = date)) +
      geom_area(fill = "#69b3a2", alpha = 0.4) +
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 0.5) +
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "#69b3a2") + scale_color_grey() + theme_classic() +
      labs(title = "Cases per month", x = "timestamp", y = "Cases")
    ggplotly(p, source = "myPlotSource1")
  })
  output$plot2<-renderPlotly({
    
    if (!is.null(myPlotEventData1())) {
      displaydat <- subset(pr59, as.Date(timestamp) %in% as.Date(myPlotEventData1()$customdata))
    } 
    else {
      displaydat <- pr59
    }
    actfr<-displaydat %>% activity_frequency("activity")
    plt<-actfr %>%plot
    plt<-plt+theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
    plt<-ggplotly(plt,source = "myPlotSource2")
    plt
  })
  
  myPlotEventData1 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource1")
  })
  
  myPlotEventData2 <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "myPlotSource2")
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible: `Error in activity_frequency: could not find function "activity_frequency"`

Comment: try now with library edeaR

Comment: I don't see how mutual filtering should work on those plots - they don't have a common variable. One is based on `date` the other on `activity`.

Comment: why am I able to subset the second when clicking on the first only?

Comment: because you are not passing any `customdata` in `plot2` but you are trying to filter `plot1` with it.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to pass the `customdata` parameter to an already existing ggplot object. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940643/9841389) helps.